# Two sides of unity object are black

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I'm new to unity and I started with something simple but all of my objects are black from the side where light doesn't shine.
I googled but other people have older unity version and mine is 2019.3.7f1 and I can't find ambient light settings like they keep saying everywhere. Other started talking about double sided shader which I have no idea what that is so I am here for help. It really triggers me when default settings of new project is broken like this. I mean who would want to have shadows like this?
[light and settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImiB2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity Lighting settings can be found by going to: `Window` (on top, Unity menu bar)  -> `Rendering` -> `Light settings`.

There you can change the "Ambient color" to a color or based upon the Skybox for example.

Comment: if you check the picture associated with my post you can see the light settings and I see only "Ambient mode" and it's locked so I don't know :/

Comment: Its locked because you have `Baked Global Illumination` turned on, a bit lower. Also, "Ambient color" becomes available when you change the setting from Skybox to Color. Everything also looks a bit over exposed I think?

Comment: thank you all is working now and the over expose I fixed by lowering the directionals light intensity from 2 to 1 is it how its done?